# Convert any dictionary to structured array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to generate a structured `numpy` array which takes field names and variable types from a dictionary. I want it to cope with most contents a user could throw at it.

Currently it works like this:

```
>>> d = dict( a=0.456, b=1234.5687020, c=4, d=np.arange(3), text='text')
>>> dtype = [(str(key), val.__class__) for key, val in d.iteritems()]     
>>> arr = np.zeros( (5,), dtype=dtype)
>>> arr
array([(0.0, '', 0, 0.0, 0), (0.0, '', 0, 0.0, 0), (0.0, '', 0, 0.0, 0),
   (0.0, '', 0, 0.0, 0), (0.0, '', 0, 0.0, 0)], 
  dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('text', 'S'), ('c', '<i8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('d', 'O')])
```

So far so good. But I now try to assign the contents of the example dictionary to the first element, it's not all good:

```
>>> for key, val in d.iteritems():
...     arr[0][str(key)] = val

>>> arr[0]
(0.456, '', 4, 1234.5687020, [0, 1, 2])
```

The numbers and the array look okay, but the text is missing. Interestingly, manually assigning to the text field gives a different result:

```
>>> arr[0]['text'] = 'text'
>>> arr[0]['text'] 
't'
```

I find this very hard to understand...

My method for determining the types seems to pick a too restrictive type. I expected that things like initializing with float32 and then assigning float64 would reduce in data loss, but I would at least expect the array to be able to hold the example data.

Is there a more robust (possibly even more elegant?) way of determining `dtype` which allows strings to work properly?

What I look for is a robust-ish way to determine the types of the dictionary contents. If I need to require that the text in the input dictionary defines the maximum string length, that is acceptable, but my function does not know beforehand which keys and types it will get.

Comment: Numpy uses fixed size primitive arrays. String types are sized, and your size had apparently defaulted to `1`. You could try using `object` but that sort of defeats the use case of `numpy`

Comment: Why not just use `pandas`? It deals with a lot of the data type munging you have to do to use numpy in this way.

Comment: *"A close look also reveals that the second number has been truncated:"* It was truncated as soon as you put it into the dictionary.  Take a look at the value of `d['b']`.  Python uses 64 bit floating point values; you can't represent `1234.568702020934022398243024302902` exactly with 64 bit floating point.

Comment: @Warren --  you're right indeed! thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a length for the type `S`:

```
dtype = [('a', float), ('b', float), ('c', int), ('d', numpy.ndarray), ('text', 'S10')]
arr = np.zeros( (5,), dtype=dtype)
for key, val in d.items():
    arr[0][str(key)] = val
```

Now:

```
>>> arr[0]
( 0.456,  1234.56870202, 4, array([0, 1, 2]), b'text')
```

Comment: What I need is a function which will work for other dictionaries -- The function doesn't know beforehand which keys there will be, and what types of variables they'll include

Answer (score 0):

The best "automatic solution I've managed to come up with is using the `dtype` of np array made from each element, rather than the `__class__` attribute:

```
>>> dtype = [(str(key), np.array([val]).dtype) for key, val in d.iteritems()]
>>> dtype
[('a', dtype('float64')), ('text', dtype('S4')), ('c', dtype('int64')), ('b', dtype('float64')), ('d', dtype('int64'))]

>>> arr = np.zeros( (5,), dtype=dtype)
>>> for key, val in d.iteritems():
...     arr[0][str(key)] = val
... 
>>> arr[0]
(0.456, 'text', 4, 1234.568702020934, 0)
```

This limits text inputs to the length of what's contained in the example data, and  will fail if any input is a numpy array (as seen above -- it classifies the array as `int` because that's what its elements are).

What I ended up doing is compiling a separate list of all elements which are strings, then adding them manually to the dtype, as `'S128'`

```
>>> stringkeys = [ str(key) for key, val in d.iteritems() if 'str' in str(val.__class__)]

>>> dtype = [(str(key), val.__class__) for key, val in d.iteritems() if not 'str' in str(val.__class__)] + [(key, 'S128') for key in stringkeys]

>>> dtype
[('a', <type 'float'>), ('c', <type 'int'>), ('b', <type 'float'>), ('d', <type 'numpy.ndarray'>), ('text', 'S128')]
```

A lot less elegant, and I suppose there are some other types which I may to catch manually but at least it works.

I had really hoped there could be an expression which automatically yields a type which will just work. And I still don't understand why the loop above does not even assign the string variable at all, although the direct assignment does assign something...